# Spell Resistance with Alchemist Bombs

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemist, spell-resistance

By default, an alchemist's bombs are not affected by spell resistance, because they are a Supernatural (Su) ability.

> Only spells and spell-like abilities are subject to spell resistance. Extraordinary and supernatural abilities (including enhancement bonuses on magic weapons) are not.

However, there are a few bomb discoveries that duplicate the effects of spells which can be affected by spell resistance; namely plague bomb:

> Benefit: The effects of the smoke created by an alchemist’s bomb duplicates the effects of *contagion* instead of *fog cloud*, filling an area equal to twice the bomb’s splash area for 1 round per level.

and cursed bomb:

> Benefit: When an alchemist creates a bomb, he can choose to have it deliver a debilitating curse. A creature that takes a direct hit from a cursed bomb must succeed at a Will save or be affected by *bestow curse*.

**In either of these cases, would spell resistance apply?** Note that neither of these discoveries on their own have the (Su) tag.

Comment: There is no spell resistance offered for *fog cloud* - though the question still contains a valid case and deserves an answer.

Comment: @NFeutz You're right, I didn't look at this too closely. In fact, there's only one "cloud"-type spell that will be affected by spell resistance, plague bomb (as contagion). I'll amend my question accordingly.

Comment: Actually, the d20pfsrd DOES have the Supernatural tag(http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo-alchemist-discoveries/plague-bomb-su/and http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateMagic/spellcastingClassOptions/alchemist.html#plague-bomb-(su)*). Cursed Bomb still doesn't on d20pfsrd, but is not on the PRD.

Answer (score 2):

### No, spell resistance doesn't apply

Regardless of the type of the bomb, either extraordinary or supernatural, neither allows spell resistance, that is unique to spells and [spell-like abilities](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Spell-Like-Abilities-Sp-). Though I agree that the ability type should have been made clear on all examples, they **default to supernatural abilities** when no type is given, as that is the type of the [Bomb ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/#TOC-Bomb-Su-) from the alchemist class.

According to the SRD, only [two discoveries](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo-alchemist-discoveries/) are spell-like abilities:

- [Glimmering Infusion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo-alchemist-discoveries/glimmering-infusion-sp/);
- [Intuitive Understanding](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo-alchemist-discoveries/intuitive-understanding-sp/).

Comment: And, ironically, Glimmering Infusion emulates Glitterdust, which is still not subject to SR...and Intuitive Understanding is a buff...